# Console.Writeline Cutting Off Large Output C#

Tags: c#

I am simply trying to output a large amount of date to the console. Here is my code...

```
Main:

    TaskResult tr = task.ExecuteCheck();
          Console.WriteLine(task.Name + "....");
          Console.WriteLine(tr.Result);
          Console.WriteLine();
          Console.ReadLine();


ExecuteCheck
 TaskResult tr =new TaskResult();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine(GetAlotOfData);
             sb.AppendLine(GetSomemoreData);
      tr.Result=sb.ToString();
            return tr;
```

When I run this the Console window only shows the last portion of the data eventhough tr.Result is populated correctly with all the data. I have never seen this behavior before. Any idea what could be happening here?

UPDATE:

```
Console.BufferHeight = Int16.MaxValue - 1;
```

seems to get the data to show, but now the scroll bar is to touchy to use. You barely move it and everything is off the screen

How can this be optimized?

Comment: How large is large? Is it simply that your console window has run out of scroll-back buffer?

Comment: That is very possible how do I resolve that

Comment: you could do a `myconsoleapp.exe > output.txt ` and then open output.txt in notepad ...

Comment: @nlstack01 I think you've got programming part of question answered... The rest of "how to deal with console output" probably should go on SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console only keeps a limited buffer of records. It keeps up to [`Console.BufferHeight`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.bufferheight%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) rows and [`Console.BufferWidth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.bufferwidth(v=vs.110).aspx) columns in memory. If your string is too wide to fit in the width or you do a NewLine it wraps it to a 2nd row. Once you fill up `BufferHeight` rows it starts dropping the oldest rows.

You can adjust the buffer height by assigning your own value to `Console.BufferHeight`, the largest allowable value is

```
Console.BufferHeight = Int16.MaxValue - 1;
```

A optimization you could potentially do is check [`Console.CursorTop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cursortop(v=vs.110).aspx) after every write to the console, that will tell you which "row" you are on. Once you get to within some limit you grow the buffer dynamically.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Some Stuff");
        GrowConsole();
    }

    const double TriggerGrowthPercentage = .90;
    const double GrowthPercentage = 1.25;
    private static void GrowConsole()
    {
        if (((double)Console.CursorTop)/Console.BufferHeight <= TriggerGrowthPercentage)
        {
            int growth = (int)(Console.BufferHeight*GrowthPercentage);
            growth = Math.Max(growth, 1); //Grow at least by 1;
            growth = Math.Min(growth, Int16.MaxValue - 1); //Don't grow bigger than Int16.MaxValue - 1;
            Console.BufferHeight = growth;
        }
    }
```

In the above example once the cursor moves to 90% of the buffer size it will grow the buffer 125% of it's current size.

Comment: This works but is too touchy cant really scroll cause everything will go off the screen even if you barely scroll through. How can I optimize this?

Comment: @nlstack01 updated with a example that dynamicly grows the console buffer as you add stuff to it.

Comment: @nlstack01 Just don't use the console.  Write the info out to a file, or use an actual UI framework, since you're dealing with content simply not well suited for a console app.

Comment: @nlstack01 Just to be clear, I totally agree with Servy. If you have that much text you might want to consider not outputting to the console at all and instead writing your results to a file instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change the console buffer height:

```
Console.BufferHeight = Int16.MaxValue - 1;
```

Also try to set the Console window height to make it a bit more readable:

```
Console.WindowHeight = Console.LargestWindowHeight;
```

Comment: Console.BufferHeight = Int16.MaxValue - 1; seems to get the data to show but now the scroll bar is to touchy to use. You barely move it and everything is off the screen

Comment: Console.WindowHeight = Console.LargestWindowHeight; Make any difference?